# using a method to resolve a chess tile colour

Tags: class, if-statement, methods

I have been looking for a while but people seem to be waaaaay ahead of me on on the chess front. All i want to do is have a method in a class to resolve the colour of a tile but my colour keeps coming up as "null".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class ChessTileTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String tileColour;
    chessTile test = new chessTile();
    System.out.print(" Enter chess move : ");
    String move = in.next();
    tileColour = test.setColour(move);
    System.out.println(tileColour);


}
```

}

> public class chessTile {
>       private String colour;
>       private String address;

```
public chessTile(){

}
public String setColour(String move){
char letter;
int number;
letter = move.charAt(0);
number = move.charAt(1);
if((letter=='a'||letter=='c'||letter=='e'||letter=='g')&&(number/2==1)){
    colour = "Black";
}
else if((letter=='a'||letter=='c'||letter=='e'||letter=='g')&&(number/2==0)){
    colour = "white";
}
else if((letter=='b'||letter=='d'||letter=='f'||letter=='h')&&(number/2==1)){
    colour = "white";
}
else if((letter=='b'||letter=='d'||letter=='f'||letter=='h')&&(number/2==0)){
    colour = "Black";
}
return colour;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you share chessTile class? (btw class names should be upper case if java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lines of `setColour(...)` are

```
char letter = move.charAt(0);   // gets ASCII character at index 0
int number = move.charAt(1);    // gets **int value of** ASCII character at index 1
```

So, for exmaple, if your string is "a1", then `letter = a` but `number = 49` because the integer ASCII value of the character "1" is 49. See this ASCII chart for more . . . http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

You will need to convert the character into a proper int.  You can do that with the following . . .

`int number = Character.getNumericValue( move.charAt(1) );`

Since you are probably getting a bad value, none of the if-statements are satisfied and a null value is returned

Comment: ok yes that's great thanks for that. Still getting a null return, are my if statements ok?

Comment: What are some example inputs? Could you edit your question to include?

Comment: Ah, what exactly are you doing with `number / 2 == 0` and `number / 2 == 1` in the if-statements? Are you doing an even/odd check? If so, I think you want `number % 2 == 0` for an even check and `number % 2 == 1` for an odd check

Comment: Yes i just figured that out, thankyou :) the % instead of the / does the trick ;)